# How to get the substrings inside the brackets in a string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have the following line of code,

```
  if((s1 != null) && (!s1.Trim().Equals("")))
```

How can I split the above string so that i can get all the text within the sub-brackets?
So the result array will contain `s1 != null` and `!s1.Trim().Equals("")`
Is there any generic way so that it can be applied to strings with n number of `&&`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string input = @"if((s1 != null) && (!s1.Trim().Equals("")))";
string pattern = @"\({2}(.*)\)\s&&\s\((.*)\){2}";

var values = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

Console.WriteLine(values[0].Groups[1]); // s1 != null
Console.WriteLine(values[0].Groups[2]); // !s1.Trim().Equals("")
```

You can also [give a name to each group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
string input = @"if((s1 != null) && (!s1.Trim().Equals("")))";
string pattern = @"\({2}(?<FirstGroup>.*)\)\s&&\s\((?<SecondGroup>.*)\){2}";

var values = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

Console.WriteLine(values[0].Groups["FirstGroup"]);  // s1 != null
Console.WriteLine(values[0].Groups["SecondGroup"]); // !s1.Trim().Equals("")
```

Shure, you should add a few checks before you access the matched results (if there are).

**Regex explanation**

1. \({2}      : matches the character ( two times;
2. (.*)       : matches any character as many times as possible;
3. \)\s&&\s  : matches a ) followed by: one or more spaces, two ampersand, one or more spaces;
4. similar to first point

Answer (score 2):

This example splits an expression into terms. Feel free to modify it to also remove the brackets around each single term. On the other hand, in your above example the brackets around the terms combined with `&&` are not required,.

```
        var expression = @"if((s1 != null) && (!s1.Trim().Equals("")))";

        // remove if, everything between outer brackets is relevant
        var firstBracket = expression.IndexOf('(');
        var lastBracket = expression.LastIndexOf(')');
        string cleansed = expression.Substring(
            firstBracket + 1,
            expression.Length - firstBracket - (expression.Length - lastBracket) - 1);

        // split and remove whitespaces
        var potentialTerms = cleansed.Split(new string[] { "&&" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(x => x.Trim());


        foreach (var term in potentialTerms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(term);
        }

        // outputs:
        // (s1 != null)
        // (!s1.Trim().Equals("))
```